# Calculate the days between dates by hand

Tags: r, date, datetime

I suspect R has a built-in method to do this, but I'm new to programming and was trying to figure out how to calculate the days between dates by hand as practice. Here is my code:

```
isLeapYear <- function(year) {
  if (year %% 400 == 0) {
    return (TRUE)
  }
  if (year %% 100 == 0) {
    return (FALSE)
  }
  if (year %% 4 == 0) {
    return (TRUE)
  }
  else{ return (FALSE)}
}

daysInMonth <- function(year,month){
  if (month == 1 | month == 3| month == 5 | month == 7 | month == 8 | month == 10 | month == 12) {
    return (31)
  }
  else if (month == 2){
    if (isLeapYear(year)){
      return (29)
    }
    else {return (28)}
  }
  else {return (30)}
}
nextDay <- function(year, month, day){
  if (day < daysInMonth(year,month)){
    return (list(year, month, day + 1))
  }
  else{
    if (month == 12){
      return (list(year + 1, 1, 1))
    }
    else{return (list(year, month + 1, 1))}
  }
}

dateIsBefore <- function(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2){
  if (year1 < year2){
    return(TRUE)
  }
  if (year1 == year2){
    if (month1 < month2){
      return(TRUE)
    }
    if (month1 == month2){
      return (day1 < day2)
    }
  }
  return (FALSE)
}

daysBetweenDates <- function(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2){
  days <- 0
  while (dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2)){
    result = nextDay(year1,month1,day1)
    year1 = result[1]
    month1 = result[2]
    day1 = result[3]
    days = days+1
  }
  return (days)
}
```

I wrote a code to determine the number of day between two dates using python. I'm now trying to convert it to R for another assignment I'm doing. When I run each indiviual function, they seem to work fine. When I call `daysBetweenDates(2012,1,1,2012,2,28)` I get the following error:

> Error in day + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: All you really need is `-`, e.g. `as.Date('2015-01-01') - as.Date('2013-01-01')`

Comment: I figured r has a built in method to do this but I'm new to programming and was trying to figure out as practice.

Answer (score 2):

```
 > as.Date("2012/02/28") - as.Date("2012/01/01")
 # Time difference of 58 days
 > as.Date("2012/01/01") - as.Date("2012/02/28")
 # Time difference of -58 days
```

Improvement suggested by Dirk in comments on just to get the number as a difference using `as.integer()`, here it is

```
 > as.integer(as.Date("2012/02/28") - as.Date("2012/01/01"))
 # [1] 58
 > as.integer(as.Date("2012/01/01") - as.Date("2012/02/28"))
 # [1] -58
```

Comment: Correct, and if you cast the result, eg via `as.integer()`, you also get just the numeric answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code isn't working is because of the way you are assigning the three elements of `result` to `year1`, `month1`, and `day1` in the `while` loop in your `daysBetweenDates` function.  If you change it like this it should work:

```
daysBetweenDates <- function(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2){
  days <- 0
  while (dateIsBefore(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2)){
    result = nextDay(year1,month1,day1)
    year1 = result[[1]]
    month1 = result[[2]]
    day1 = result[[3]]
    days = days + 1
  }
  return (days)
}
```

If you do `return <- list(2012, 1, 1)` and then `return[1]` and compare that with `return[[1]]` you  should see the difference.  This is common mistake when using lists.  You might want to take a look at this for an excellent discussion of subsetting: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html.